# SQL: How can I return the highest ranking record of similar records, based on one column value?

Tags: sql

This seems like it should be easier than I'm finding it.  I have a table that contains both first and last names (specified by a type ID) and a frequency of how common the name is.  For example:

```
NameType | Name      | FrequencyPercent
1          John        3.267
1          Thomas      1.987
1          Wilson      0.945
2          Smith       4.528
2          Wilson      2.221
2          Thomas      0.437
```

I want to be able to query out a list of First Names (NameType = 1) that will only include the name if it is more likely to be a First Name than a Last Name (based on the FrequencyPercentage).  With this dataset, my FirstNames query would include John and Thomas, and my LastNames query would return Smith and Wilson.

Hopefully I explained that well.

Thanks ahead for a little help,

Russell Schutte

Comment: By "if it is most likely to be a First Name" do you mean "if it is more likely to be a first name than a last name?"

Comment: [Case in point](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nl0HqlbX7dc) (humour).

Comment: Yes Chris...  That's what I mean.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're looking for first names when the frequency is higher than the frequency as same name as  last name

This works for first names. You just need to reverse it for last names

```
CREATE Table YourTable
(
NameType int,
name varchar(20),
FrequencyPercent decimal(12,4)
)

INSERT INTO  YourTable
VALUES (1 ,'John', 3.267),
(1 , 'Thomas',      1.987),
(1 , 'Wilson',      0.945),
(2 , 'Smith',       4.528),
(2 ,  'Wilson',      2.221),
(2 ,   'Thomas',      0.437)

SELECT firstNames.name
FROM
      YourTable firstNames 
LEFT JOIN YourTable  lastNames 
 ON firstnames.Name = lastNames.Name
    AND lastNames.NameType  =2
     and firstnames.FrequencyPercent < lastNames.FrequencyPercent
WHERE firstNames.NameType  =1
      AND
      lastNames.name is null
```

results in

```
name
--------------------
John
Thomas
(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Why `AND lastNames.name is null`? In fact, why doesn't that force the query to return 0 records?

Comment: Conrad... thank you so much for your help.  I think that's it exactly.  I'll run some testing against my real dataset to be sure, but this looks like it.  Maybe I could have explained it better like this:  First Names query returns ALL FirstNames minus the ones that are more likely to be a last name.  :-)  Thanks Again!

Comment: Indeed Conrad.  You are the man.  That works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Cunningham. `lastNames` is left joined. This means that `lastNames.name` will only be null when its NOT Matched. The match condition is the name is the same and the type is last name  and the frequency is higher than the first name

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're wanting...

This will get you the First Names:

```
SELECT *
FROM [NameTable]
WHERE FrequencyPercent > 1.0
    AND NameType = 1
ORDER BY FrequencyPercent
```

Comment: Hi Narnian, this must be my bad, since others have also answered, but not what I'm looking for.  First, I have no guaranteed that a FrequencyPercent greater than 1 is important.  I'm going to Edit my post above, if I can... and better explain it.  Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Top 5 most common first names:

```
select Name
  from Names
  where NameType = 1
  order by FrequencyPercent desc
  limit 5;
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the reply.  I'm on MSSQL, which seems to not like the "Limit" keyword... and I'm not looking for the most common names - I'm looking for a list of all the names that are more likely to be a first name than a last name.  It's kindof an exclusive query - "Return All of the Names that are a first name, when they are more likely to be a first name than a last name."

Answer (score 0):

If you want top 2 for both first and last name, you can do UNION ALL.

```
select name 
FROM table
where Nametype = 1
order by FrequencyPercent desc
limit 2
UNION ALL
select name 
from table
where nametype = 2
order by FrequencyPercent desc
limit2
```